# CSS header doesnt go all the away across (Safari 5.1.5. and all other browsers too)

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser

I have this site...

http://willruppelglass.com/

it looks good on my machines and all browsers I tested but someone told that the black header doesn't go all the away across the header. What am I doing wrong....before in all browsers there was a big white space to the right...so I changed this..

```
.headerNav {
    color: 
    black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1280px;
    padding-top: 140px;
    padding-left: 230px;
    }
```

to this

```
.headerNav {
    color: 
    black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1050px; /* decrease the width of the div to compensate for the padding-left */
    padding-top: 140px;
    padding-left: 230px;
    }
```

but now the header doesn't appear to go all the way across

The browser in question is Safari 5.1.5.

any help would be appreciated, thanks in advanced,
J

here is a screen shot on what I am dealing with...
[image]

Comment: its seems fine in safari

Comment: mine too, but some reason some people are telling its not, im using the same version of safari, but hes using a wide screen

Comment: on which resolution they getting this

Comment: You have several errors in the HTML of your site, such as semi-nested comments. See [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwillruppelglass.com%2F&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0). No idea if those cause the problem, but it won't hurt to correct them.

Comment: Are you trying to fix something you were told about but haven't seen yourself? How do you know there is any problem with your site? I don't see the issue in Safari or any other browser.

Answer (score 0):

1 rep says that he is shrinking the browser smaller than 1050px and then scrolling to the right, which is something that is not fixable (the width of `<body>` cannot be larger than the viewport). The same thing happens with the background for the header and footer of Stack Overflow.

Comment: You don't fix it. The `<body>` element cannot be larger than the viewport since the scrollbar is on that content. This `bug` exists on every site that has bars that span the entire width.

Comment: added a screen shot so you know what I am talking about.

Comment: This is the issue I described. See how there is a scroll bar at the bottom and the page is scrolled over. You can reproduce this on any browser. As soon as you make the browser smaller than the width of your content, then scroll over, the page will do that.

Comment: if i disable the bottom scroll bar will that fix my issue?

Comment: Yes, if you use a design where the content re-flows with no width, the issue will go away. You will most likely still have a minimum width for your site, so it will still happen when you hit that, but it won't happen at the larger resolutions it's happening at now.